# Web Api 2 all errors logging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Some errors get uncaptured (like ModelBinding exceptions or route change failure exceptions) when I use ExceptionLogger and ExceptionHandler implementations.

The question is how to log all exceptions fired in Web Api 2 app?

Btw, I use OWIN to host it.

Comment: Are you sure these are not caught by a `ExceptionFilterAttribute` ?

Comment: Not catching such exceptions. Maybe there is some other code or web.config param need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

What about a catch-all middleware?

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log  
    }
});
```

Comment: When I access not existing URL, I got in to try statement, but not into catch. Looks like WebAPI handles the exception and returns the response.

Comment: And it only works (even though half-works) when I put it before builder.UseWebApi(config); code, which is quite understandable, though.

Comment: Yes, you have to put it first in the pipeline.

Comment: I got it, but it doesn't enter "catch" clause anyway.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post http://www.jayway.com/2016/01/08/improving-error-handling-asp-net-web-api-2-1-owin/